# jQuery creating multiple alert boxes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, alert

I am trying to validate phone number in a form. I execute a function on submit of form which has the procedure of validating the phone number. If the phone number is not 10 digits I stop the function alerting the user that they need to enter a valid 10 digit phone number.

```
var valPhone = validatePhoneNumber;
    var valPhoneThis = valPhone(txtPhoneNumber);

    if(!valPhoneThis)
    {
        alert("Please enter your 10-digit phone number, numbers only.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
```

Not sure what is wrong here but it displays multiple alert boxes with the same message. I am creating a jQuery mobile application if that helps.

```
$('#create-new-account-button').click(function()
{
    $('#create-account-dialog').css('display','block');

    txtFirstName = $('#ca-first-name').val();
    txtLastName = $('#ca-last-name').val();
    txtDateOfBirth = $('#ca-date-of-birth').val();
    txtZipCode = $('#ca-zip-code').val();
    txtPhoneNumber = $('#ca-phone-number').val();

    radGenderMale = $('#ca-radio-gender-male').val();
    radGenderFemale = $('#ca-radio-gender-female').val();

    txtLogin = $('#ca-email-username').val();
    txtPassword = $('#ca-password').val();

    // VALIDATION

    // Validate Gender

    var valGender='';

    if(document.getElementById('ca-radio-gender-male').checked) 
    {
        // Male radio button is checked
        valGender = "M";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ca-radio-gender-female').checked) {
        // Female is checked
        valGender = "F";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select a gender");

    }

    // Validate phone number
    var valPhone = validatePhoneNumber;
    var valPhoneThis = valPhone(txtPhoneNumber);

    if(!valPhoneThis)
    {
        alert("Please enter your 10-digit phone number, numbers only.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }

    // Validate for Blank Fields
    // Iterate through all fields to verify there is data in all of them
    var blankArray = [];

    $(".create-account-field").each(function (i) {

        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        var thisProp = $(this).prop('placeholder');

      if ( thisVal == "" ) 
      {
          blankArray.push(thisProp);
      }
      else 
      {
          // console.log(thisVal);
      }

    });

    var blankArrayString = blankArray.join(", ");
    if(blankArrayString == "")
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
```

Comment: How you bind the submit event?

Comment: Please show us more code.  We can't get anything from what you've posted.  How is this function called?  What triggers it?  Is that the whole function?

Comment: this is because your function runs multiple times and its likely because of bubbling

Comment: please show, how you bind this function to click event of element

Comment: I have added the click event that triggers the whole function.

Comment: If it helps, the ajax call also gets fired twice. It has been mentioned only once. I don't have a very complicated mWeb app. It's one HTML and one JS.